# 'software-properties-gtk' does not work in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, python, update-manager, gtk

I have read the same issue but without success for me. When I run "software-properties-gtk" in the terminal, it shows this:

```
$ software-properties-gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 37, in <module>
from softwareproperties.gtk.SoftwarePropertiesGtk import SoftwarePropertiesGtk
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 46, in <module>
from .DialogCacheOutdated import DialogCacheOutdated
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/    DialogCacheOutdated.py", line 28, in <module>
from aptdaemon.gtk3widgets import AptErrorDialog, AptProgressDialog
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/gtk3widgets.py", line 42, in <module>
gi.require_version("Vte", "2.91")
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 83, in require_version
(namespace, version))
ValueError: Namespace Vte not available for version 2.91`
```

The command `update-manager' has the same problem:

```
ValueError: Namespace Vte not available for version 2.91`
```

Any ideas to resolving them?

Comment: Please show us the output of: `dpkg-query -W python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets`

Comment: Hi @Gunnar. Here it is: "python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets 1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2.0pmo1.0~trusty"

Comment: That's not the official trusty version of that package. You seem to have got it from `ppa:anton+/photo-video-apps`, and packages from that PPA cause the problems you have encountered.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I am not completely sure if I have understood the solution.  Do I have to remove `ppa:anton+/photo-video-apps` from the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d path`? After that what repository should I have to add? My knowledge about this kind of issues is not enough to solve it. Could you explain to me step by step how I could solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix your system would be to replace all packages from that PPA with the official packages. It can be done this way:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:anton+/photo-video-apps
```

That would also disable the PPA from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Comment: I disabled the PPA from the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. But the same problem happens when I update, install and run 'software-properties-gtk' and 'update-manager'. I do not know what I am doing wrong. Any other ideas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @jos: Disabling it manually is not sufficient. Run the commands I suggested.

Comment: I disabled it in the way you suggested (`sudo ppa-purge ppa:anton+/photo-video-apps`) but it happened an error, so I eventually did it manually. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: @jos: That command is a convenient way to replace the packages from the PPA with the official ones. If it failed, you still have the incompatible version of `python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets`, for instance. I'd suggest that you try the command again and show the resulting error message by editing your question.

Comment: This is the error I had when I tried to do it before I did it manually:</br>
`$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:anton+/photo-video-apps`</br>

`Updating packages lists</br>
PPA to be removed: anton+ photo-video-apps</br>
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: anton+ photo-video-apps`

Comment: @jos: Well, it looks like `ppa-purge` cannot be used, then. One thing you can do is to use _Synaptic_ to replace the currently installed version of the `python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets` package with the version in trusty-updates.

Comment: OK. I removed `python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets` via Synaptics. According to this `http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/all/python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets/download` I added the following code line `deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main` to `/etc/apt/sources.list` in order to replace the older version with the version in trusty-updates, but without success. The warning message is the following: "python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets: Depends: python3-aptdaemon(=1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2) but 1.1.1-1ubuntu5.2.0pmo1.0~trusty is to be installed". I don't have idea how to go on.

Comment: @jos: Ok. Looks like you need to replace other packages built by [the aptdeamon source package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty-updates/aptdaemon) in the same manner.

Comment: I give up trying to solve this issue. I don't know how to compile this package. Thank you for your help.